# MS words including header inside

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ms-word

Hi I am using laravel to create the html page and I manage to convert from html to ms words, but right now I want to add in header inside. How can I do that?

My codes is something like that:

```
<body>

    <a class="word-export" href="javascript:void(0)">Export to Word (.doc)</a>

    <div class="word-content">

                <br><br>
        <?php 
        $mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');
        echo $mytime;
        ?>  <br>
Disclosure Agreement

<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/FileSaver.js') }}"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.wordexport.js') }}"></script>

<script>
$('.word-export').click(function(events){
    $('.word-content').wordExport();
});
</script>
</body>
```

I want to show something like that on every page where it will show Disclosure Agreement:

[image]

Comment: what is the laravel part ?

Comment: It just a php framework that I used to create the page

Comment: It's a jquery library which does the work, Laravel tag is not needed in this question

Comment: Oh i see will remove it, updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported by the library.

The *jquery.wordexport.js* library creates a file in .mhtml format which can be understood by Word. This format is a multipart MIME format and actually does support headers and footers, namely as a separate parts inside the MHT file.

However, the jQuery library only does a basic conversion of the page's HTML into a single part and does not allow you to add a header. However, if you only want to add a fix header, you should be able to modify the code in jquery.wordexport.js to add the header part.